# PHP assign score for item of array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with these score values:

```
    $r = Array
(
    [C] => 11.00.00
    [B] => 11.00.00
    [G] => 11.00.00
    [F] => 10.02.00
    [A] => 10.00.00
    [D] => 09.00.00
    [E] => 08.00.00
    [H] => 08.00.00
    [I] => 07.00.00
    [K] => 06.00.00
    [J] => 06.00.00
)
```

I need assign a number of position, but that the same scores will have the same position, ex:

```
A : 1 -- draw score
B : 1 -- draw score
C : 1 -- draw score
D : 4 -- not 2, because the previous position
E : 5 -- normal
F : 6 -- normal
G : 7 -- draw score
H : 7 -- draw score
I : 9 -- not 8, because the previous position
...
```

I've tried group items by scores and start with numbering:

## group

```
$result = array();
foreach($r as $k => $v)
{
    $result[$k] = array_keys($r, $r[$k]);
}
```

## numbering

```
$p = $c = 1;
foreach($result as $k => $v)
{

    $ac = count($v);
    if($ac==1)
    {
        $p = $p+$c;
        $c = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $c = $ac;
    }
    $result[$k] = $p;   
}

print_r($result);
```

but i have this:

```
Array
(
    [C] => 1
    [B] => 1
    [G] => 1
    [F] => 4
    [A] => 5
    [D] => 6
    [E] => 6
    [H] => 6
    [I] => 8
    [K] => 8
    [J] => 8
)
```

I need:

```
Array
(
    [C] => 1
    [B] => 1
    [G] => 1
    [F] => 4
    [A] => 5
    [D] => 6
    [E] => 7
    [H] => 7
    [I] => 9
    [K] => 10
    [J] => 10
)
```

How I can sort properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $result = Array
(
    "C" => "11.00.00",
    "B" => "11.00.00",
    "G" => "11.00.00",
    "F" => "10.02.00",
    "A" => "10.00.00",
    "D" => "09.00.00",
    "E" => "08.00.00",
    "H" => "08.00.00",
    "I" => "07.00.00",
    "K" => "06.00.00",
    "J" => "06.00.00"
);

$prev='';
$i=1;
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
$ii = $i++;
    if($value==$prev)
    {
        $tt[$key] = $tt[$p];
    }else
    {
        $tt[$key] = $ii;
    }
    $prev = $value;
    $p = $key;

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($tt);
```

***output***

```
Array
(
    [C] => 1
    [B] => 1
    [G] => 1
    [F] => 4
    [A] => 5
    [D] => 6
    [E] => 7
    [H] => 7
    [I] => 9
    [K] => 10
    [J] => 10
)
```

Comment: I had done it, but I had to use 3 foreach... vote for your answer because it is the most optimal. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Group the results by value then use `krsort` to sort from largest to smallest (note: you can skip `krsort` if your initial array is already sorted). Score the results by iterating through the grouped results and increasing the score by the # of elements in each group as you go.

```
$r = array (
    'C' => '11.00.00',
    'B' => '11.00.00',
    'G' => '11.00.00',
    'F' => '10.02.00',
    'A' => '10.00.00',
    'D' => '09.00.00',
    'E' => '08.00.00',
    'H' => '08.00.00',
    'I' => '07.00.00',
    'K' => '06.00.00',
    'J' => '06.00.00',
);

$grouped_results = array();

foreach($r as $k => $v) {
    $grouped_results[$v][] = $k;
}

krsort($grouped_results);
$score = 1;    
$scores = array();

foreach($grouped_results as $group) {
    foreach($group as $result) {
        $scores[$result] = $score;
    }

    $score += count($group);
}

print_r($scores);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [C] => 1
    [B] => 1
    [G] => 1
    [F] => 4
    [A] => 5
    [D] => 6
    [E] => 7
    [H] => 7
    [I] => 9
    [K] => 10
    [J] => 10
)
```